# Need to build another EXE

Tags: vb.net

I wish to have two EXE files in my project.  Say one EXE has startup form ABC.vb
and other is BCA.vb
I am not able to change the name in Build so whatever is my startup file, my exe file's name remains the same.  How to change it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you're asking for. Can you try to clarify your question? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to change the startup form or do you want to change the project or solution name in order to change the exe name?

Answer (score 4):

A project builds to one assembly, no matter what.

What you need to do is add another project to your *solution*.  You can do this by right clicking in the tree, and going to New... Project.  Then, drag your code that you want to build separately into this new project.

After this, when you build, you will get two EXEs, or whatever the project is set to.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
But how to make the existing forms that 
I want to start with, part of new 
prject.  Do I need to add all dependant 
forms to this new project?
Thanks

Comment: Yes, just drag over any forms that you wish to move to the new project.  Think of these projects as separate, as they are.  The only thing that binds the two are that they both load at the same time when you open your solution, and that they both build when you run a build.

Comment: Thank you.  And what if I want that a form is shared
by both projects?  By dragging over it, does it move or remains 
in the origial prject too?

Comment: If you want a form (and anything else) that can be used in both projects, add a third project and make it a "class library" type.  Then add your shared code to it.  Then, add a reference from the other two projects to this class library project.  That way, you can maintain it in one location.  The class library compiles to a DLL.